# Set types: ['node'] for a single file

Tags: typescript

I know that I can set `{ "compilerOptions": { "types": ["node"] } }` in `tsconfig.json` to prevent errors like `TS2304: Cannot find name '__dirname'.`.

But what if I want to allow that in only one file, can I set this option in a single file?

The file where I want to allow `__dirname` is `vite.config.ts` which lives adjacent to `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: you can use multiple tsconfig files